# INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, teradata

Can you help me to find the appropriate script conversion from this Teradata script to Azure SQL:

```
CASE WHEN ( ABS(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MIN_OUCID_TMS) - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MIN_ONEID_TMS)) )>= 2 -- prevent interval overflow
         THEN INTERVAL '01 00:00:00' DAY TO SECOND  ----set to one day max interval if very large
                ELSE ABS(( MIN_OUCID_TMS - MIN_ONEID_TMS ) DAY(4) TO SECOND)
             END
                 ELSE NULL
     END
```

Thank you!

Comment: First you'll need to decide how you want to represent the result, since Azure SQL DB does not have INTERVAL types. Maybe use DATEDIFF with appropriate precision (seconds? milliseconds?) - depends on what you do with the value.

Comment: Thanks! Please, can you give me an idea how to use here datediff?

Comment: Some sample input data and expected results would be really useful here please!  Just a few records to demonstrate the principle, but yeah as Fred says, no interval type in Azure SQL DB, so it may be you need to write out in words the logic of what you want to achieve to help people understand.

Comment: Thanks, but firstly i wanted to understand what the TD script does, as i am not sure i understand it correctly...any idea here would be very useful..

Comment: You've posted only a fragment of a CASE expression. The WHEN is checking just the YEAR part of two timestamps; if they are more than a year apart it sets the result to just a one day interval. Teradata DAY TO SECOND intervals are limited to 9999 days 23 hours 59 minutes 59.999999 seconds so in principle checking for "very large" makes some sense but I can't explain why 1 day was chosen as the result for this edge case. The (first) ELSE computes the difference between the two timestamps as a DAY TO SECOND interval and takes the absolute value; (4) because the default is 2 digits for DAY part.

Comment: Also can't say why you'd want (for example) the 367 day difference between 2021-01-01 and 2019-12-31 considered "large" when a 730 day difference between 2020-12-31 and 2019-01-01 would not be, but that's the existing logic.

Comment: Thanks very much for your feedback, it helped a lot.  As interval datatypes are not supported in Synapse, I created a workaround which i will post here, maybe this would be   helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround for interval datatype:

```
CASE WHEN ( OUCID_REC_CNT > 0 ) THEN 
                 CASE WHEN ( ABS(DATEPART(YEAR,MIN_OUCID_TMS) - DATEPART(YEAR,MIN_ONEID_TMS)) )>= 2
                      THEN '01 00:00:00'
                      ELSE 
                      convert(varchar(20),abs(datediff(ss, MIN_OUCID_TMS, MIN_ONEID_TMS)/86400)) + ' ' + format(dateadd(ss,abs (datediff(ss, MIN_OUCID_TMS, MIN_ONEID_TMS)),0),'HH:mm:ss')
                 END
             ELSE NULL
        END
```